# User control exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, exception, user-controls

**Question**

Okai, I have a few user controls which I'm reusing several times. For example, I have a `NumericUpDown` control with some code behind it, but I want to catch the exception `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` but I have no idea how...  It also only fires the first time I change the value, I have more than 1 instance of this control in my form.

**What I've tried so far**

```
private void num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in your code.  Instead of trying to hide it and pretend it didn't happen, you need to fix your code.  We can't see it.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't hide anything at all. This is all the code I have at the moment.

Comment: Where does the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception that you want to catch actually happen?

Comment: @CL. It happens when the amount I enter is bigger than 100. I wanted to catch all the exceptions in the custom control, I have no idea if this is a smart thing to do or not. I thought it would be more readable at a later stage.

Comment: I did not ask "when" but "where". What particular function throws this exception?

Comment: @CL. I don't have a particular function yet, it happens whenever the number is greater than 100. I don't really know how to explain, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Simply list the type of the desired exception instead of the base Exception class.

```
try
{

}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception)
{

}
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't trigger the catch part at all, only the first time I use the user control. Sorry, will edit my question

Comment: @FoxyShadoww Maybe it does not throw after the first time?

Comment: Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @FoxyShadoww No way to know without seeing what's in the `try` block

Comment: Nothing, I only set a breakpoint and a `Console.WriteLine` test line.